# Javascript Date object returns wrong date

Tags: javascript, linux, date

I have trouble with JS Date object.

I am working on timezone settings.
By creating a zic file (like /usr/share/zoneinfo/Europe/Paris) I'm able to manual set my local date time parameters.
For my tests, I'm doing an offet of 1 year.
Everything works fine on the system side :

```
date -u ==> Thu Jun  4 10:18:27 UTC 2015
date ==> Sat Jun  4 12:18:29 BST 2016
```

But

```
console.debug(new Date()) ==> Sun May 10 2015 13:50:27 GMT-k631 (BST)
```

Does someone have seen such strange behavior and Date object ?

Thanks

Thom

Comment: Is this with all browsers/environments you have tried, or just a specific browser/environment?

Comment: I assume that linux `date` checks the zoneinfo file and outputs the system time + the zoneinfo adjustment. The browser is using the system time and knows nothing about the zoneinfo. This would be my assumption and is not necessarily correct. I am unable to repeat what you are doing because there really isn't enough information.

Comment: Yes linux date uses zoneinfo, and I modify my local time settings by gernerating a tzfile (using zic).
My browser is webkit (using Qt). I'm installing firefox to check if I have the same behavior on it

Comment: On firefox,  `console.debug(new Date())` returns the UTC, but not local time. And `new Date().toLocalDateString()` returns me a wrong date, which is not my local time or UTC time.

Comment: Things work fine on my linux install, but I haven't created any zone/tzfile files using `zic`. My locale is set to CEST, `date` gives the correct local datetime and `-u` the correct UTC datetime. All browsers also give the correct local and UTC time.

Answer (score 0):

The browser Date object is using you clock to determine the time.
So if you set your location ( +2 hours, -5 hours etc ) there is going to be a difference between the system side and the client side.

You can "normalize" the date to Greenwich time ( +0 ) and then set the time object based on your current offset and the desired offset.

Comment: Thanks for your anwser, I'll check that.
But what I don't understand is that Date object should use the system date, right ?

When I set an UTC offset < to 1 year (for example 1 month and 1 day), everything is Ok, JS Date is the same than my local system time.

Comment: There is no notion of Client/Server,
It is an embedded system with a web based application GUI, the time you see on the HMI is the system time. So Server machine=Client machine.
So in that case, the dates should be the same